# Crystal Reports Date Format

Tags: crystal-reports

how can I format the day from a date field to print like 1st 2nd 3rd and so on? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution for this.

```
NumberVar DayIn := Day (PrintDate);
Totext (DayIn , 0 )
& (if DayIn in 4 to 20 then 'th' else
if remainder (DayIn , 10) = 1 then 'st' else
if remainder (DayIn , 10) = 2 then 'nd' else
if remainder (DayIn , 10) = 3 then 'rd' else 'th')
```

from http://www.kenhamady.com/news0910.shtml

Comment: great.. this works for 11th 12th and 13th too..   i had wondered about the "4 to 20" clause when i first looked at it.